# iOS Linker Command Failed using Core Plot Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker, core-plot

So I'm building an application with CorePlot, and when I tried to run it i got the following errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/tcbl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceTracker-    chbhtqlxwipamtailjamrakmkpuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a,     
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/tcbl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceTracker-chbhtqlxwipamtailjamrakmkpuy/Build/Intermediates/FaceTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/FaceTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main-cocoatouch.o and /Users/tcbl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FaceTracker-chbhtqlxwipamtailjamrakmkpuy/Build/Intermediates/FaceTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/FaceTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main.o for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I read somewhere that I need to add to other linker flags: `-ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot` But this doesn't seem to be anywhere in the project info or build settings, and I'm not sure if this even has anything to do with my error.  Any help demystifying this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select your project and go to the Build Settings tab, you should find it listed under Linking. Make sure you have the advanced/complete view of the tab. The field you want to enter those under is "Other Linker Flags".

Hope that helps!